# Class diagram of a bank confusion

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I found the following class diagram through google(from researchgate) and I am confused with the relationship between the Account class and the Client class. AFAIK, this way the diagram shows that multiple clients can be related to one account. But shouldn't it be the other way around? I can create multiple accounts in a bank and be their owner. According to me the cardinality should be 0..n on the Account class and 1 on the Client class because one owner can have multiple accounts. Am I missing something?

[image: UML Class diagram for a banking system]

Comment: I think it should be `1..n` in the Client side. An account has to have at least one owner. The rest means that in this particular Bank each client can only have an account, not multiple accounts. Or it is wrong as you said.

Comment: I think it makes a less sense for an account to have multiple owners(and at least one) than an user to have multiple accounts. Here AFAIK, is said that an account can have 0 or more owners which makes a little sense to me.

Comment: This is more a banking question than  a uml question. An account can have multiple clients (e.g. a couple husband/wife) and a client can have multipe accounts. So I'd assume you'd have an n:m relation. Since your model looks like a design model you might want to model Account 1:n Bank details and Bank details n:1 Client.

Comment: I agree with @WolfgangFahl. To me it's strange that they have multiple account lists which can have zero(???) to many accounts inside. No idea what the reason for that could be.

Comment: It depends on the type of account, but in general banking it’s many-to-many with the join being a form of delegation. An account can have multiple owners and those owners can delegate rights to access an account to others usually. In the reverse a single client can ‘own’ multiple accounts and may be delegated rights to access other accounts too. E.g. a business ‘owns’ an account but has directors that have authority to sign and delegate actions to administrators. That would be for domestic currency, foreign currency accounts can be different.